# Probability of throwing a die

Tags: probability

**Question**: How many times should we throw a die if we want that the sum of points obtained
was at least 4500 with probability $p \geq  0; 975?$
(use the central limit theorem).

I know that the probability of getting a given value for the total on the dice may be calculated by taking the total number of ways that value can be produced and dividing it by the total number of distinguishable outcomes. So the probability of a $7$ on the dice is $\frac{1}{6}$ because it can be produced in $6$ ways out of a total of $36$ possible outcomes.

Could some one help me on how to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what CLT is? Also, the probability of $7$ is $\frac16$, on two die rolls summed, not one die roll.

Comment: @DonThousand you're right  the probability is $\frac{1}{6}$. I have idea of what CLT is. That the sampling distribution of the mean tend to a normal distribution as the size grows. But how can I apply it in this questions

Comment: I would read up on the exact theorem, not just a rough understanding of it. It'll be obvious once you understand it.

Comment: You need to  put several ideas together for the solution to this. I hope the Outline in my Answer will help. It is OK to answer your own question. Maybe you can try that after you follow my outline. In any case case please leave a Comment on progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outline:

For a single roll of the die the mean number of
points is $\mu = 3.5$ and the variance
of the number of points is $\sigma^2 = 2.916667.$
These values can be found using the definitions of the mean and variance of a discrete random variable.

Let $T_n$ be the total points on $n$ independent rolls of the die.
Then $E(T_n) = n\mu,$ $Var(T_n) = n\sigma^2,$ and
$SD(T_n) = \sigma\sqrt{n}.$

According to the CLT, You want
$$P(T_n \ge 4500) = 
P\left(\frac{T_n -n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\ge\frac{4500 -n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}}\right)\\ \approx 
P\left(Z\ge\frac{4500 -n\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{n}} = 1.96 \right)= 0.975.$$

In the next-to-last member of the above equation, use known values of $\mu$ and $\sigma,$ solve for $n$ and round up to the next higher integer.

*Note:* On account of the following simulation
in R, I'm guessing $n$ is not far from $1320.$

```
d = replicate(10^6, sum(sample(1:6, 1320, rep=T)))
mean(d >= 4500)
[1] 0.973992
```

Comment: Should the 1.96 be -1.96?

Comment: Thanks @BruceET for this solution. It was helpful

Comment: @student010101. Obviously not, because 4500 is intended to be in the upper tail.